# Keep source maps when saving files in a different folder with Gulp

Tags: gulp, source-maps

I'm trying to make a Gulp task that takes JS files, runs uglify on them, adds a `.min` suffix to the filename and then saves them in a destination folder that is different than the source folder. The tricky part is to keep source maps working...

```
gulp.task('uglify-js', function () {
    // Fetch CSS files
    return gulp.src(['assets/js/*.js', '!assets/js/*.min.js'])

        // Start source map
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))

        // Uglify JS
        .pipe(uglify())

        // Add file suffix
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))

        // Save source map
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())

        // Save output to destination folder
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'));
});
```

I tried many different options, but the source maps don't seem to work...
Does anyone know the right way to do this?

My packages:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.8.10",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
  "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
  "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.2"
}
```

Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Have you tried without `loadMaps: true` ?

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but no success :/ I've editted my question a bit, because I can't seem to get it to work at all now... Gonna keep trying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is gulp-rename doesn't currently support gulp-sourcemaps, as mentioned in [their latest issue](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename/issues/37).

One alternative is to use a different lib that supports sourcemaps, for example [gulp-concat](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat), which supports renaming the files. If you don't want to concat your files, however, you could always open a pull request against gulp-rename to add sourcemaps support, as [documented here](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps#plugin-developers-only-how-to-add-source-map-support-to-plugins).

**Update:** As of 2015-03-14 gulp-rename now [supports sourcemaps](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename/pull/38)

Comment: If I don't rename it and just save the uglified file to public/js then sourcemaps still don't work :(

Comment: I've seen certain .js files break sourcemaps due to their content. Which .js files are you trying this on?

Comment: a jquery plugin im working on.. I replaced it with some dummy js, but still the same...

Comment: @ivanv what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you not see the sourcemap comment inside the resulting file? I reproduced what I think is your situation and it seems to be working for me, see: https://github.com/chmontgomery/stackoverflow-28255221 and the resulting `public\js\main.js`

Comment: Thanks for the example. It worked indeed. I think I found my issue... Today I opened the webpage through explorer, but yesterday I was testing through the browser-sync local "server", which I start with Gulp. And there seems to be some sort of glitch: when you view the console in Chrome devtools it keeps saying error on "line 1". When I hard refresh now, the correct line number appears (although I think I also refreshed yesterday). When I view it without browser-sync, it seems to work just fine now (even with the rename). Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! :)